# A Django field consisting of several fields

Tags: django, django-models, field

I want a "composite" Django fields which corresponds to two (rather than one) database columns.

In fact the composite field should consist of two `ForeignKey` fields.

Otherwise it should behave like a normal field. For example it can be used in a form to input data.

It seems that Django 1.10.1 does not support this. I may try to write a patch. Any advice?

Comment: "the composite field should consist of two ForeignKey fields" => why not using a many to many? What are you concretely trying to achieve? I'm sure there is another way...

Comment: @FrançoisConstant In my real task, I have **two** foreign keys which should work together as one field (for example I may make 3 such "composite" fields in one model, then it will contain 2*3=6 foreign keys), it is not many-to-many (it is 1-to-two)

Comment: It sounds to me like another model/table. I insist, I still don't know what you want to achieve. What are these 2 foreign keys? Users, pages, payments?

Answer (score 0):

I've (partially) implemented it in https://bitbucket.org/portonv/composite-fields